# Output from apply lambda function with groupby is object, want to convert to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

I have a dataframe, which i applied lambda funciton with groupby, the lambda function generated two values as output, and the output is object data type.

I tried with output.to_frame().reset_index() and pd.DataFrame(output), neither really worked.

output.to_frame().reset_index() made the second column name 0, but i can't display the second column with output.0. After output.to_frame().reset_index() looks like this:

[image]

What's the best way to convert this object output from lambda function with groupby to a dataframe looks like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to do it upfront (*before/when using groupby*) but you can still try this :

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop("0").tolist(), columns=["score", "value"]))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  id  score  value
0  a      1      2
1  b      4      5
2  c      6      7
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason i'm still getting error on '0', as the '0' may not be a real column, it's auto generated after i use output.to_frame().reset_index(). Seems if function generate the two output into tuple, I tried with out = pd.DataFrame(list(output)), and append that to id column and that seems to work.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you `print(output.head(3).to_dict())` ?

Comment: It returns this: {'id': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 0: {0: (1, 2), 1: (4, 5), 2: (6, 7)}}

Comment: Well, in this case, replace `df.pop("0")` by `df.pop(0)`.